# Class inheritance in Mule Java / POJO Component

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am trying to use a base class with common methods and to extend it other more specific classes.

```
public class myClass extends myBaseClass {}
```

The extended class I am using as a Java component in a flow:

```
<component class="org.example.MyClass" doc:name="Java"/>
```

When I am not calling methods from the parent class, everything works well. But each time I try calling one Mule is throwing an exception:

```
DefaultJavaComponent{vtigersapFlow1.component.9760166}. Message payload is of type: String
```

In my base class I am using:

```
@Lookup
private MuleContext muleContext;
```

and and a `NullPointerExcception` is thrown when I am doing:

```
muleContext.getRegistry().get("system.uri");
```

Comment: Updated with more infos.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `@Lookup` annotation is not honoured correctly in a class hierarchy.

Instead of looking values in the registry, you should receive them by injection, i.e. get `system.uri` by injection.

You may find that switching to Spring beans will help a lot in doing so. `component class=` is really for basic stuff.